# how to get the selected nodes in xml using javascript im getting blank page as o/p

Tags: javascript, xml

here im not getting any display from the selected node, how we do it in javascript of       node to be selected in this xml file

```
 JAVASCRIPT
  <html>
 <body>
 <script type=text/javascript>
 function getTable(xmlDoc){
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SystemRecord.xml");
 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {    
    if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("cl_system")[0].childNodes.length == 0) {          document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("cl_system")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}}
 getTable(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cl_system")[0]);
 }
```

XMLFILE

```
 Systemrecord.xml     
   <System>
   <cl_system>dsaf</cl_system>
   <Rtppath>fgdfas123</Rtppath>
   <JDFpath>agfdg</JDFpath>
   <Orginalpath>fga</Orginalpath>
    <Url>fgfa</Url>
  <UID>ragf</UID>
  <Password>vacx</Password>
  <localpath>sfdsv</localpath>
   <thumbnailurl>dfdsv</thumbnailurl>
   <Printer_path>gsagf</Printer_path>
  <JMF_Url>vcvfag</JMF_Url>
  <FTP_Path>fdsdavf</FTP_Path>
</System>
 </System>
```

Comment: What do you think that `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SystemRecord.xml")` does?

Comment: oops sorry ..... no idea where we have to load the xml file

Comment: So your question is "How to load an XML file in JavaScript"? Sounds like a good point to start some research...

Comment: yep i got the o/p thanks